# Does an extern variable declaration also declare an (object) entity?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

<sub>*(All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/), with **emphasis** mine in the standard quotations)*</sub>

---

### Background

I'm trying to answer the question whether or not the named variable `arr` below

```
extern int arr[];  // declaration; type is int[]
int arr[10];       // definition; type is int[10]
```

is transferrable to that of a single entity, such that this entity has different type depending on from which context it is referred<sup>(1)</sup>, or if the entity's type is always the same, and it's just the type of the variables (whose name denotes entity) that differs depending on context.

<sub>(1) The only other case I know of where this applies [is for enumerators](https://dfrib.github.io/same-entity-different-type/) (which are entities), which have different type depending on whether they are referred to from inside the enumeration that defines them (the type is that of the underlying type of the enumeration) or from outside of it (the type is that of the enumeration).</sub>

### Question

- Does an `extern` variable declaration also declare an *entity* (the variable name denoting the entity), such that this entity has a different type depending on whether its referred to by its `extern` variable declaration or its re-declaration and definition (`int[]` vs `int[10]` above)?
- Or, is the type of the *entity* always that as specified by the object definition (`int[10]` above), whereas the difference in type is only due differences in the *type of the variable* depending on from what context we refer to it?

### Details

[[basic]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#3) defines an *entity* as:

> An *entity* is a value, **object**, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, or parameter pack.

[[dcl.stc]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.stc#5) covers the `extern` specifier, and how it can be applied to *declare* a *variable*:

> The `extern` specifier shall be applied only to **the declaration of a variable** or function. [...]

[[basic]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#6) defines a *variable* as:

> A *variable* is introduced by **the declaration** of a reference other than a non-static data member or **of an object**. **The variable's name**, if any, **denotes the** reference or **object**.

From here, it seems straight-forward, as per [[basic]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#4) and [[basic]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#5), that an `extern` variable declaration (which must have a name) is no special case, and its name does indeed denote an *entity*:

> /4 A *name* is a use of an *identifier*, *operator-function-id*,
> *literal-operator-id*, *conversion-function-id*, or *template-id* that **denotes an entity** or label ([stmt.goto], [stmt.label]).
>
> /5 **Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a *declaration*.**
> Every name that denotes a label is introduced either by a goto
> statement or a labeled-statement.

as it declares a *variable* whose *name* denotes an *object* (which is an *entity*).

However,  [[intro.object]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#1) says:

> [...] An *object* is **created by a definition**, [...].
>
> [...] An *object* has **a type** [...].

but the *type* of a *variable* declared using the `extern` specifier is not necessarily the same as that of the *object* which is *defined* elsewhere (in the re-declaration an non-`extern` definition of the variable):

```
#include <type_traits>

extern int arr[];  // extern declaration
using A = decltype(arr);

int arr[10];       // definition
using B = decltype(arr);

// All asserts below pass.
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<A, B>, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<A, int[]>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<A, int[10]>, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<B, int[10]>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<B, int[]>, "");
```

If the name `arr` as introduced by the `extern` variable declaration (and only that) denotes an *entity*, particularly that of an object, it would arguably mean that this *entity* has a different type depending on context/scope, which would arguably violate [intro.object]/1 regarding an object (*entity*) to have *"a [single] type"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, confusion between “variable” and “object” exists throughout the standard (consider that [basic.stc.auto] completely neglects the possibility of recursion), including **which** of those is an “entity”.  However, [basic.types]/6 addresses this pretty directly:

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown bound and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and complete later on; the array types at those two points (“array of unknown bound of `T`” and “array of `N` `T`”) are different types.

The hedge “declared type” is used in other places like [dcl.type.auto.deduct] to talk about the type “written” for something even though the “real thing” has a different (completed or deduced) type.  This is an example of another unfortunate style of description in the standard: that of specifying **transformations** applied to the program without making clear the order in which they are applied or which rules apply at each stage.  Usually it’s fairly clear what context must be applied for a rule to make sense: `decltype` doesn’t consider a subsequent declaration that specifies an array’s size and doesn’t produce a type of `auto`.

Comment: Thanks. So in this particular example (trying to sort something out from the confusion), the actual entity would be that of the object, and have the type of `int[10]`, whereas the ”declared type”, which can be both `int[]` and `int[10]`, does not describe entities or an entity in the sense that these entities or this common entity has different type?

Comment: @dfri: The entity (according to my understanding of the (eventual) intent of the wording) is the variable.  In some translation unit, it might never have a complete type, but if it’s defined anywhere there is an object associated with it that definitely has type `int[10]`.  The declared type is a property of the variable that is “subjective” in that the answer can differ for different query points.